# Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following SQL Server error in ASP.net C#:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

My SQL query is:

```
string query = @"update Conference set Conference_name='" 
    + name + "',AIMS='" + AIMS + "',Scope='" + scope 
    + "',Submission_Deadline='" + submissionDay 
    + "',Notification_Deadline='" + notificationDay 
    + "',Camera_Ready_submission='" + cameraReadyDay 
    + "',Early_authors_registration='" + earlyAuthorsDay 
    + "',Start_Date='" + startDay + "',End_Date='" + endDay 
    + "',Location='" + location 
    + "' where Conference_ID= '" + id+"'";
```

Comment: Can you output the contents of the variable `query` instead of executing it, and post it here?

Comment: @emilios : What is the datatype of startDay and endDay variable and which format of date you are using? Off-topic: don't use hard-coded string. Use parameterized query.

Comment: I hope none of that data comes from postback values or user entered data.  You should be using parameterized queries, it also helps solve some kinds of problems like this.  If any of that data originates from anywhere outside of the server, the it's ripe for sql injection attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is time to add some validation. May I suggest the [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx), with [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type.aspx) set to Date?

Comment: And be aware that the valid ranges from a Sql datetime is different than the range of a .Net datetime. Specfically, .Net datetime.MinValue is less than Sql's minimum value for datetime. You can compare to SqlDateTime.MinValue in c#.

Answer (score 1):

I think your query is OK, it's your data that is bad.  One of the date fields (startDay, EndDay, NotificationDay) does not look like a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

one of your values for a date, probably start or end date is not able to be converted to a datetime. Would help to see the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is related with c# ToString() behaviour. Due to "culture" of your application, ToString() method was defaulted to a value.

"2011 jan 13" can be stringified "2011-01-13" or "2011-13-01" due to your app culture setting.

And this may result in error when trying to find 13. month of year.

To overcome this issue, i recommend to use SqlCommand and set parameters...

please see http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/dynamicsqlparameters.html

Example can be easily converted to c#.